# GCD and LCM.. Need help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im sure this is obvious... but i was absent in class and am having a hard time finding it on google. If someone would be so kind to help explain to me how to find the GCD and LCM of the number:

$17^{88}\cdot31^5\cdot37^{2}\cdot{59}^{1000}$

$19^{922}\cdot37^{12}\cdot53^{3678}\cdot59^{29}$

Comment: Usually we ask for the gcd or lcm of **two** numbers, sometimes more, never fewer. Can you check the wording of the question?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the last line

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** GCD requires only primes present in both numbers to the lowest exponent seen in either number. LCM requires every prime present in both numbers to the highest exponent seen in either number.
$\def\lcm{\mathrm{lcm}}$

---

Let's take some smaller numbers to see how the process works. Let's find $\gcd(60,63)$ and $\lcm(60,63)$. These numbers are small enough we can just list out the possible factors to find the GCD.

factors of $60$: $1, 2, \color{red}{3}, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60$

factors of $63$: $1, \color{red}{3}, 7, 9, 21, 63$

Scanning the lists we see that the largest factor they share is $3$.

Similarly, we can list out the multiples until we find one that they share.

multiples of $60$: $60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 420, 480, 540, 600, 660, 720, 780, 840, 900, 960, 1020, 1080, 1140, 1200, \color{red}{1260}$

multiples of $63$: $63, 126, 189, 252, 315, 378, 441, 504, 567, 630, 693, 756, 819, 882, 945, 1008, 1071, 1134, 1197, \color{red}{1260}$

The first multiple they have in common is $1260$. So we have $\gcd(60,63)=3$ and $\lcm(60,63)=1260$.

Now that the tedious way has been demonstrated. Let's relate what is going on to the quick way (and for the large numbers you have the only way to reasonably solve the problem). Let's take our numbers and our answers and factor them into primes.

$60 = \color{blue}{2^2*\color{red}{3^1}*5^1}$

$63 = \color{blue}{\color{red}{3}^2*7^1}$

$\gcd(60,63) = 3 = \color{red}{3^1}$

$\lcm(60,63) = 1260 = \color{blue}{2^2*3^2*5^1*7^1}$

I've colored $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ the factors that relate to the GCD. By definition, the GCD is the greatest common divisor. This means that it needs to divide into both numbers without leaving a fraction. $2$ is obviously not a prime in the GCD since one of the numbers is odd (i.e. $\frac{63}{2}$ doesn't simplify). But why isn't $3^2$ the GCD? $3$ is a prime found in both numbers. If we try dividing, we get $\frac{63}{3^2} = 7$ and $\frac{60}{3^2} = \frac{20}{3}$. So $3^2$ can't work because there are too many $3$s. So the GCD is formed from the primes present in both numbers but taken to the smallest exponent seen in either number.

I've colored $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ the factors that relate to the LCM. Notice that our LCM contains everyone of the primes listed for the two numbers. This is because the Least Common Multiple is a number that both of the numbers will divide into without leaving a fraction. Why isn't the LCM equal to something smaller like $420$? If we check, $\frac{420}{60} = 7$ and $\frac{420}{63} = \frac{20}{3}$. $420$ is too small. It doesn't have enough $3$s to handle being divided by $63$. So to ensure that out LCM can be divided by both numbers, we have to use every prime present in the problem and to the highest exponent seen in either number.

Answer (score 0):

The H.C.F. of two numbers is the greatest number that divides both of them completely while LCM is the smallest number that both the given numbers would divide completely.
For example, $$24 = 2^3\cdot 3$$
$$30 = 2\cdot3\cdot5$$
So the GCD = $2^{min(3,1)}\cdot3^{min(1,1)}\cdot5^{min(1,0)} = 2\cdot3 = 6$
And the LCM= $2^{max(3,1)}\cdot3^{max(1,1)}\cdot5^{max(1,0)} = 2^3\cdot3\cdot5 = 120$

We took the minimum of powers in HCF because we want the HCF to divide both the numbers completely. The minimum of powers means that when dividing each number by HCF, the powers of each prime number in HCF will obviously reduce the power of the same prime in the number.
So$\frac{2^3\cdot3}{2\cdot3} = 2^{3-1}\cdot3^{1-1}=4$
$\frac{2^1\cdot3^1\cdot5^1}{2\cdot3} = 2^{1-1}\cdot3^{1-1}\cdot5^{1-0}=5$

In case of the LCM, since we are taking the maximum, the LCM when divided by one of the numbers, the powers of each prime in the number reduce the powers of the same prime in the LCM.

---

So for $17^{88}\cdot31^5\cdot37^{2}\cdot{59}^{1000}$ and 
$19^{922}\cdot37^{12}\cdot53^{3678}\cdot59^{29}$

HCF = $17^{\text{min(88,0)}}\cdot19^{\text{min(0,922)}}31^{\text{min(5,0)}}37^{\text{min(2,12)}}53^{\text{min(0,3678)}}59^{\text{min(1000,29)}}$
$=17^{0}\cdot19^{0}\cdot31^0\cdot37^2\cdot53^0\cdot59^{29}$
$=\boxed{37^2\cdot59^{29}}$

LCM= $17^{\text{max(88,0)}}\cdot19^{\text{max(0,922)}}31^{\text{max(5,0)}}37^{\text{max(2,12)}}53^{\text{max(0,3678)}}59^{\text{max(1000,29)}}$
$=\boxed{17^{88}\cdot19^{922}\cdot31^5\cdot37^{12}\cdot53^{3678}\cdot59^{1000}}$